# Coaxial cable with electric flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

I had a question when I solved some examples of coaxial cables.
I want to find the E and D field using $\rho_s = {Q \over {2\pi r L}}$.

Here is my question:
Why is the inner surface of the cylinder negatively and the outer surface positively charged?

Comment: I tried to clean the post up a bit, if you don't mind. By "cylinder", do you mean the dielectric (or air) between the inner conductor and the outer shell?

Comment: yes right! I want to express coaxial cables using cylinder.

Comment: also the cylinder can express dielectric also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charges could equally well be the other way round and then the direction of the electric field would be reversed.

Perhaps the negative charges where placed on the inner conductor and an equal number of positive charges were induced on the inside of the outer conductor?

There will be a potential difference across the conductors due to an excess of electrons in one negatively charged ($-Q$) conductor and a deficit of electrons in the other positively charged ($+Q$) conductor.

As $E = - \frac{dV}{dr}$ there will thus be an electric field between them.

The quantity $\rho_S$ which you quote in your question is the surface charge density (charge per unit area) on the conductors.

As the system is nicely symmetrical you can use Gauss's law to find $E$ and $D$.

**Later**

I think that I have finally understood what the symbols mean.

[image]

The charge on a length $L$ of the inner conductor is $Q = \rho_S 2 \pi a L$

Using Gauss's law for the cylinder of radius $\rho$ and noting that the displacement $\vec D$ is radial so the top and bottom surfaces of the cylinder do not contribute to the integral we have

$\int _S \vec D_{\rho}\cdot d\vec S = D_{\rho} 2 \pi \rho L = Q = \rho_S 2 \pi a L$ from above where $D_{\rho}$ is the displacement at radius $\rho$.

This gives the equation you were insure about  $D_{\rho} = \dfrac {a \rho_S}{\rho}$

Comment: Thanks!
I have some more question.
I can find ρs using that quote, but  I want to find Dρ also.
the solution says Dρ = a * ρs / ρ .
how can i think about that equation?

Comment: I don't understand why  ρs  multi a / ρ.
also I'm confusing about relation Dρ with ρs.

Comment: I think that you will need to add to your original post the actual question which you are trying to answer.

Comment: The origin question is "Let us select a 50cm length of coaxial cable having an inner radius of 1mm and an outer radius of 4mm. the space between conductors is assumed to be filled with air, the total charge on the inner conductor is 30nC. we wish to know the charge densirt on each conductor, and the E and D fields.

Comment: I want to find Dρ.
the solution says Dρ= a*ρs/ρ.
I don't know why using length of only "a" and how to think about that equation.

Comment: @DONGHUN I think that I have answered your question?